# Null coalescing operator, unpredictable behavior

Tags: c#, dart

I feel confused about results of flow piece of code:

```
bool? _true = true;

bool? val1 = _true ?? true && false; //true
bool? val2 = (_true ?? true) && false; //false
```

I thought result should be the same, anyone can explain such as behavior?
I noticed that it works identically at least in c# and dart so it means that should be good reason for that.

Comment: `_true ?? true && false` is equivalent to `true` (nothing after ?? is evaluated) while `(_true ?? true) && false` is equivalent to `true && false`

Comment: `_true ?? true && false` === `_true ?? (true && false)`

Comment: Please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/ , paying attention to the statement "The following sections list the C# operators starting with the highest precedence to the lowest". A similar question might be "Why is `2 + 3 * 5` different to `(2 + 3) * 5`"? It's not unpredictable. You just need to know the rules

Comment: There is very little in synchronous programming which is unpredictable.

Comment: @Jamiec Well, undefined behavior is unpredictable...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because of [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/), the `&&` operation is performed before `??`. So your first line is equivalent to:

```
bool? val1 = _true ?? (true && false);
```

Answer (score 5):

The null-coalescing operator has a fairly low precedence. In the first example `true && false` evaluates to `false`, leaving `true ?? false` which evaluates to `true`.

In the second example the parenthesis are evaluated first (to `true`), leaving `true && false` which results in `false`.

Answer (score 5):

The logical and operators (`&&`) have higher precedence than the null coalescing operator (`??`).

So

```
bool? val1 = _true ?? true && false; //true
```

is equal to `_true ?? (true && false)`. Since `_true` is not null, the null coalescing operator returns this value (`true`).

In the second case

```
bool? val2 = (_true ?? true) && false; //false
```

the part in brackets is `true` again, but ANDed with `false` it results in `false`.

See [C# operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/)

Answer (score 3):

If we add the implicit brackets into the first case it makes more sense

```
bool? _true = true;

bool? val1 = _true ?? (true && false); //true
bool? val2 = (_true ?? true) && false; //false
```

As `_true` is not null, nothing after the `??` is evaluated.